# Can I download multiple zip files from server into one zip file?

Tags: php

I want to download multiple zip files from a server, and while downloading this all zip file append and download as a one zip file from server.

Comment: while download or after download?

Answer (score 1):

To pack all zip files in the e.g. current directory and send that to the browser, try:

```
 header("Content-Type: archive/zip");
 passthru("zip - -0 *.zip");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use PLCZIP for zip operations and recommend it to you too

craete new pclzip object

```
 require_once('pclzip.lib.php');
 $archive = new PclZip('archive.zip');
 $v_list = $archive->add('myfile1.zip,myfile2.zip,myfile3.zip');
```

http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip

http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/user-guide/57